# SyntaxError when using python pattern matching with condition and a wildcard

Tags: python, pattern-matching, wildcard, python-3.10

I want to use pattern matching to pass through two variables and I need to use conditions with both of them in different cases.

```py
match '12345', '23456':
    case _, b if '456' in b:
        print('True')
    case a if '123' in a, _:
        print('True')
    case _:
        print('False')
```

I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on that second case. The first one seems to be working though.
It seems like one cannot use wildcard `_` after condition.
I know I could use two match/case constructions or classical if/elif/else, but I would prefer single match/case construction to work.

Python version - `3.10.6`

Comment: I'm not sure what your second case is meant to mean.

Comment: Were you trying to attach the condition to the match variable, like matching `a, _` and then putting a condition on the `a`?

Comment: @quamrana it means I only care if there is the `'123'` substring in the first argument (disregarding the second argument `b`), then the `case` should trigger.

Comment: @user2357112 not sure what you're asking, sorry. Do you mean `case a, _:` and then inside of the `case` add an `if` statement? Then how to proceed to the next `case` if the `if` is `False`?

Comment: @quamrana you can see that the second case is not really different from the first one. It's only position of the wildcard.
The whole condition for the function is basically `return True if there is '123' in the first argument or there is '456' in the second argument else return False`

Comment: Syntactically, the guard is the keyword `if` followed by a `named_expression`. A `named_expression` cannot contain a comma; an `expressions` construct is a comma-separated list of `expression` constructs (and a `named_expression` is one kind of `expression`). See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've simply got the wrong idea about how the syntax works.

(disclaimer: I've never used this new feature of python 3)

I think you should have the pattern to the left and the `if` on the right:

```py
match '12345', '23456':
    case _, b if '456' in b:
        print('True')
    case a,_ if '123' in a:
        print('True')
    case _:
        print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html.

The guard in a match statement is defined by this rule:

```
guard: 'if' named_expression
```

which is to say, the keyword `if` followed by a `named_expression`. `'123' in a, _` is *not* a `named_expression`, though. Why not? In short, because it contains a comma.

```
named_expression:
    | assignment_expression
    | expression !':='

expression:
    | disjunction 'if' disjunction 'else' expression 
    | disjunction
    | lambdef
```

You can follow `disjunction`, etc, to see the full definition of `expression` (the myriad rules are how precedence is encoded in the grammar). The *comma*, however, is part of an `expressions` value, which is  intuitively a comma-separated sequence of `expression`s.

```
expressions:
    | expression (',' expression )+ [','] 
    | expression ',' 
    | expression
```

Semantically, it wouldn't make sense anyway. Even if you parenthesized it to read

```
case a if '123' in (a, _):
    print('True')
```

what's the value of `_`? That's a tuple display, not a pattern, so `(a, _)` has to evaluate to some value in order to evaluate `'123' in (a, _)`. The pattern is `a`, on the other side of the `if`, which has been matched against the tuple.